# Problem with resetting scrollbars when left mouse press event is sent to QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwidgets

So, I am currently trying to implement dragging mode on mouse with ScrollHandDrag everytime user presses middle button on QGraphicsView. The problem is - to actually drag with scroll hand drag mode you have to left click.

My solution for that was to simply override MousePressEvent method in a class that inherits after QGraphicsScene and catch that middle mouse button event here, access QGraphicsView that uses this QGraphicsScene, set ScrollHandDrag drag mode on the QGraphicsView and send one more event to QGraphicsView from QGraphicsScene that would be a left mouse click. This way someone could enable ScrollHandDrag with only middle mouse button, and actually drag with just that button.

This is essentially done like this:

```
case Qt::MiddleButton: {
    views()[0]->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);

    QMouseEvent eventGraphicsView(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, event->pos(), event->scenePos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    QApplication::sendEvent(views()[0]->viewport(), &eventGraphicsView);
    break;
}
```

MousePressEvent had to be overriden in class that inherits after QGraphicsScene since QGraphicsView isn't available considering how the code is being structured now.

The problem here is, even though it works properly and I can drag on QGraphicsView - everytime I try to drag, scrollbars reset their position to whatever it was before. It seems like the view jumps to last position with it's scrollbars.

So the question is - why is that? Should the event be different? When I implemented this with for example ctrl + left click usage, everything works fine, although in this implementation I don't send any type of event to QGraphicsView, so I guess the issue lies somewhere here.

Comment: Your reconstruction of the event is not valid, because you're using scene positions. Nonetheless, you should override the `mouseButtonPress` (and release) in the view, not the scene.

Comment: @musicamante so what you're trying to say - the coordinates that are being sent out from QGraphicsScene in the QMouseEvent are relative to QGraphicsScene, and that's why they are not correct when they arrive in MousePressEvent inside QGraphicsView, doing that scrollbar moving? So is there a way to make some offset to the coordinates in QMouseEvent, so they'd be correct when they arrive in QGraphicsView?

Comment: You could remap the scene positions to the view, but it seems pointless: why don't you do that in the view, as suggested above? For your purpose, the scene shouldn't even receive the event in the first place.

Comment: Well, right now how the app is done is that, that QGraphicsView is basically integrated in .ui file, so uic generates code with the QGraphicsView class inside. I'd have to do a smaller/bigger refactor here to take this class outside, make another class, make it inherit after QGraphicsView, override MousePress/Release event, and then initialize UI with that class, instead of autogenerating it. This refactor task probably comes next, maybe I'll do it before enabling dragging (you can correct me if that's how it's done usually in Qt apps, since I'm beginner myself).

Comment: You can just use widget promotion, so that you'll only need to implement the QGraphicsView class, there's no need for complete refactoring. Alternatively, install an event filter on the viewport.

Comment: @musicamante nice, just googled it (didn't know about it before) - how that works is you basically break up widget parts to separate UI files, and then you insert the newly broken part to the "main UI" by using "Promote to" function on plain Widget object, and then inserting it with the custom made widget class?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your explanation, so I'll give you mine: when you promote a widget in Designer, it will be used as a "placeholder" for the UI with the same widget type, and you give it a *promoted class name*, which will be the actual class you will use in your code (taken from the header file set in the promotion dialog). The UI will fundamentally be the same, allowing to set properties for the specific type. In your code you'll implement the custom class (that must inherit from the same base type, even indirectly), then override `mousePressEvent()` and/or anything else you need.

Comment: When you build the program, the uic code will be created with the given custom class instead of the standard one, since it's declared in the includes, and when the program is run `setupUi()` will correctly create an instance of your custom class, with all your overrides in place. This is extremely useful, because you can easily create custom widget subclasses and use them in the UI via Designer. The difference is that you will not see *the* custom class, but only the placeholder one: this means that if, for example, your custom class draws its contents differently, you will not see that »

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I get it. In the span of last two hours I successfully implemented that and it works. Read here and there and voila. Didn't know about that and it seems a lot easier to "extend" classes this way instead of what I've wrote previously.

Comment: » in Designer (it doesn't really know anything about the custom class) but just the basic one; this is also valid for custom Qt properties defined in the class, which can only be set with manual addition of dynamic properties. All that would only be possible by using a custom Designer plugin, but most of the time (like in your case) it's not necessary: you only need to use a QGraphicsView with custom behavior at runtime, and that's what widget promotion allows.

Comment: Yes, it's way easier and extremely useful, as it allows to use custom widget classes in the UI design without complicating things: you just take care of the UI, and implement extra behavior by code. The behavior in Designer will still be the default one (that of the base widget type, QGraphicsView in your case), both in editing and preview, but the actual program will behave as expected. Note that you can even set custom signals and slots you may have defined in your subclass to eventually automate connections in the UI: right click on the widget, and open its Signal/Slot editor from the menu.